# Symfony 4 -- error when I try to create a Session Proxy

Tags: php, symfony, session, symfony4

I follow the instructions in https://symfony.com/doc/master/session/proxy_examples.html,

I update my framework.yaml

```
framework:
    secret: '%env(APP_SECRET)%'
    #default_locale: en
    #csrf_protection: ~
    #http_method_override: true

# uncomment this entire section to enable sessions
session:
    # With this config, PHP's native session handling is used
    handler_id: App\Session\CookieEncryptedSession

#esi: ~
#fragments: ~
php_errors:
    log: true
```

I also create my ownclass:

```
<?php
namespace App\Session;

use Defuse\Crypto\Crypto;
use Defuse\Crypto\Key;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Proxy\SessionHandlerProxy;

class CookieEncryptedSession extends SessionHandlerProxy
{
  private $key;

  public function __construct(\SessionHandlerInterface $handler, Key $key)
  {
    $this->key = $key;

    parent::__construct($handler);
  }

  public function read($id)
  {
    $data = parent::read($id);

    return Crypto::decrypt($data, $this->key);
  }

  public function write($id, $data)
  {
    $data = Crypto::encrypt($data, $this->key);

    return parent::write($id, $data);
  }
}
```

When I try to run the server with the console I get this error:

```
In CheckCircularReferencesPass.php line 67:

  Circular reference detected for service "App\Session\CookieEncryptedSession  
  ", path: "App\Session\CookieEncryptedSession -> App\Session\CookieEncrypted  
  Session".
```

Any idea where is the mistake?

Thanks

Oskar

Comment: I faced a scenario where I need to implement a SessionEncryptionProxy. Just leaving this here in case somebody needs such functionality.
https://github.com/coral-media/http-foundation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The autowiring is trying to inject the service to itself as the service implements the interface required on the constructor. `CookieEncryptedSession` implements `SessionHandlerInterface` via:

```
class SessionHandlerProxy extends AbstractProxy implements \SessionHandlerInterface
```

Setup in your services the service: CookieEncryptedSession manually so you can select the SessionHandlerInterface service you want.

- NativeSessionHandler
- NativeFileSessionHandler
- DbalSessionHandler
- Etc